# Speed up RcppArmadillo: How to link to OpenBlas in an R package

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am working on an R package which uses RcppArmadillo. I am trying to take advantage of faster matrix multiplication found in OpenBLAS. In the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#blas_lapack_replacements) of the C++ armadillo library, it says if we have OpenBLAS on our machine then Armadillo would use OpenBLAS instead of BLAS. However, when I compile my R package, I get something like this:

```
g++ -m64 -std=c++11 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -o PackageTest.so class1.o class2.o class3.o class4.o class5.o class6.o class7.o RcppExports.o class8.o class9.o class10.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
```

So it is compiling with the `-lRlapack` and `-lRblas` options. How can I properly modify the `Makevars` and `Makevars.win` files to have RcppArmadillo compile the package with the option `-lopenblas`? My attempt to solve this problem was to modify the `Makevars` file in the following way:

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
PKG_CXXFLAGS =-fopenmp -std=c++11 -lopenblas
PKG_CXX1XFLAGS = $(PKG_CXXFLAGS)
```

The package did compile with `-lopenblas`, but is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

That is a problem with your RedHat installation which chose to rely on the internal LAPACK sources for R when installing R --- plus the fact that RcppArmadillo uses whatever R uses.

On my Debian/Ubuntu based machine, it happens differently. Ie for

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction("arma::mat foo(arma::mat x) { return x + x;} ", depends="RcppArmadillo", verbose=TRUE)
```

I get (inter alia)

```
g++ -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions \
    -Wl,-z,relro -o sourceCpp_4.so file677111d81351.o \
    -fopenmp -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath \
    -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
```

and we see `-llapack -lblas -lgfortran` as expected.

Comment: In your case how would you compile with openblas? Also, Is `-llapack` and `-lblas` different in terms of performance from `-lRlapack` and `-lRblas`?

Comment: Debian offers a choice between _pluggable_ alternatives all of which are accessibly via `-llapack -lblas`.  The default is basic ie 'reference' BLAS, and OpenBLAS is available if you want it.  OpenBLAS is likely better than the default that ships with R, or in the reference BLAS.

Comment: Your question, though, it RedHat specific so I would take it to the r-sig-fedora list.  It has nothing to do with Rcpp or RcppArmadillo.  The packages are all fine, _how R was installed for you_ is what matters here.

Comment: I don't think this is a fedora specific because ultimately other people are going to try this on a variety of OSs, so it's important to document how we modify the makevars file to have the R package compile using OpenBLAS. I am actually using my package on a ubuntu machine aslo, so it would be great to show us how you would modify the makevars file to compile with `-lopenblas`.

Comment: I think you still miss my point.  It works by default when R is installed correctly.  R comes with an entire manual on 'Installation and Administration' -- did you see that?

Comment: Also your second part of your question is just wrong.  You added a *link instruction* to a *compiler flag*.  Wrong.   Add the `-lopenblad` to `PKG_LIBS` but that does not undo the fact that R will already give you its -- and that is _precisely_ the crux of both your problem, and core of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Instructions for compiling R, OpenBLAS and linking R with OpenBLAS (GNU/Linux)

**I believe your biggest problem is linking R to the OpenBLAS library. So the steps I write below can help you succeed in this link.**

**Compiling OpenBLAS**

Initially download the **R** and **OpenBLAS**(**Open** Optimized **BLAS** Library) source codes in **OpenBLAS**. In the file directory, perform the following steps.

```
tar -zxvf OpenBLAS*
cd OpenBLAs*
make -j $nproc
sudo make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/
```

or

```
git clone https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git
cd OpenBLAS*
make -j $nproc
sudo make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/
```

**Note**: This will make the compilation run faster using all the features of your CPU. To know the number of cores, do: `nproc`.

**Compiling Armadillo C++  with OpenBLAS**

For those who use **C++** codes in **R** using the **Rcpp** library, setting up the **Armadillo** with the **OpenBLAS** library may be of some benefit.

```
tar -xvf armadillo*
cd armadillo*
./configure -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/
cmake . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/
make -j $nproc
sudo make install
```

**Note**: Further details regarding the compilation of the **Armadillo** library can be found at https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code.

**Compiling R with OpenBLAS**

After compiling **OpenBLAS**, download the **R** code. It is not necessary to compile **R** to make use of **OpenBLAS**, but compiling the language may bring some benefits that may be insignificant depending on what is being done in **R**. That way, download the source code of the language **R**.

**Note**: In my operating system, Arch Linux, **OpenBLAS**) was installed in the `/opt` directory. Search for the **OpenBLAS**installation directory in your GNU/Linux distribution.

In the directory where the **R** was downloaded, do the following:

```
tar -zxvf R*
cd R-* && ./configure --enable-R-shlib --enable-threads=posix --with-blas="-lopenblas -L/opt/OpenBLAS/lib -I/opt/OpenBLAS/include -m64 -lpthread -lm"
make -j $nproc
sudo make install
```

Most likely the [**OpenBLAS**](https://www.openblas.net/) library will be bound to [**R**](https://cloud.r-project.org/). To check, run  in the [**R**](https://cloud.r-project.org/) the `sessionInfo()` code. Something like the output below should appear:

```
Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas_haswellp-r0.3.6.dev.so
```

If linking does not occur, follow the steps outlined in the code below.

We need to link the **R** with the file `libopenblas_*`, created in the process of compiling the library **OpenBLAS**. In my case, the file is **ibopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.20.so**. Look for this in `/opt/OpenBLAS/lib` or in the directory where **OpenBLAS** was installed on your GNU/Linux system. Also look for the **libRblas.so** file directory found in the [**R**](https://cloud.r-project.org/) language installation directory. In Arch, this directory is `/usr/local/lib64/R/lib`.

```
cd /usr/local/lib64/R/lib
mv libRblas.so libRblas.so.keep
ln -s /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.20.so libRblas.so
```

Start a section of language **R** and do `sessionInfo()`. You should note something like:

```
Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas_haswellp-r0.3.6.dev.so
```

To make use of multithreaded processing, do `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` before starting a [**R**](https://cloud.r-project.org/) section.

**NOTE**: For intel processors,`sudo cpupower frequency-set -g performance`, can boost performance. Read more at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling.

Comment: This doesn't look right: `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`.  To get multi-threading from OpenBLAS, you need more than one thread.  You're also using an outdated version (0.20.0) of OpenBLAS. New releases are at https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/

Comment: Being equal to 1 means the number of threads per core. In my case, there are 4 cores with 1 thread per core.

Comment: install.packages("ropenblas")
ropenblas::ropenblas()