# Linking R with AMD BLIS Library (in Ubuntu)

Tags: r, blas

I would like to link the AMD BLIS library with R to perform some benchmarking/profiling. It seems that R does not need to be compiled specifically against other BLAS implementations. For example, other BLAS libraries (OpenBLAS, Intel MKL, Atlas) simply need to be installed and the BLAS implementation being used can be easily changed via `update-alternatives`. For example, this web page walks through several BLAS implementations:

https://csantill.github.io/RPerformanceWBLAS/

And the BLAS library used in R can be verified via `sessionInfo()`. However, the BLIS library is not an option that comes up once it is installed via `update-alternatives`. I cannot find a guide for linking AMD BLIS with R anywhere. The only other post that I can find mentioning it does not explain how it was achieved:

[R performance on Ryzen+Ubuntu: openBLAS/MKL, Rcpp and other improvements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619670/r-performance-on-ryzenubuntu-openblas-mkl-rcpp-and-other-improvements)

I am working on an AMD Ryzen threadripper 3990x 64-core processor × 128 and I would like to see how the BLIS library performs against the other options. Any assistance in linking R with BLIS would certainly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem as you last week. From my understanding, R needs to get compiled with BLIS. I did the configuration step like this: `./configure --with-blas="-lblis -I{PATH_TO_BLIS}/include -L{PATH_TO_BLIS/lib" --with-lapack="llapack"`. I think it is necessary to specifiy `-with-lapack="llapack"`, because BLIS doesn't include a LAPACK implementation.

Comment: This is what I was anticipating. I am held up right now and won't be able to check this immediately, but when I do if this works (as I anticipate it will) I will accept this as the correct answer. I imagine you had success going this route? Yet I wonder why BLIS doesn't create an instance of libblas.so.3 though?

Comment: Yes, it was successful. Can't answer your last question unfortunately. Right now I am trying to use libflame instead of LAPACK, but no success so far.